# Can you add a Domain User to Samba?

Tags: linux, windows, permissions, samba, windows-domain

Instead of adding a local user on a Linux computer using the command `smbpasswd -a username`. But how can you go about adding a domain account user on a Linux computer (provided that Linux is added to a Windows Domain)? The command `smbpasswd -a domainAccountName` gives me an error saying it has failed to add a user entry?

I can add local usernames, but I get weird permission errors when connecting to the Share from a Windows System, because I need the local username's credentials, rather than the domain account's credentials? Does anybody know the correct way of adding Domain Account users to a Linux Samba Share?

Hope this is clear.
Thanks